# Is there a specific linguistic term for the following practice of constructing new words/characters?

Tags: terminology, etymology, semantics, borrowing

I have in mind examples such as the *[Scheingallizismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheingallizismus)* (lit. appearance of Gallicism) in German which are words/phrases constructed from French origins but are themselves unknown in French speaking countries. For instance, the German word *blamage* meaning "disgrace" was coined from French *blamieren* (to embarrass) and the nominal suffix *-age*, and is even pronounced like French. For non-alphabetic writing systems, I have in mind the Japanese *[kokuji](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E8%A3%BD%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97)/wasei kanji* (国字/和製漢字) which are characters coined mainly based on logographical rules of Chinese characters (interestingly, while many of these *kokuji* are only seen in Japanese, a few of them did wind up adopted back into simplified Chinese); for instance, the kanji 凪 meaning "calm" was coined from the radical (i.e. component form) ⺇ and the character 止 meaning "to stop".

In such cases, although the constructed words/phrases/characters are mostly unknown in their adopted source languages, native speakers of the adopted languages are often able to recognize some parts of these coined words/characters, but only to a limited extent.

My question: **is there a linguistic term specifically accounting for the phenomenon described above?**

I've thought about [calques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque), [loanwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword), [semantic loans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_loan), [false cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate), [neologisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism), [phono-semantic matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phono-semantic_matching), and so on; but none of them seems to accurately describe it. I do admit that this is a field that I am relatively ignorant of, and please correct me if I have made any mistakes.

---

Update: After some further research, it seems to me that the concept of [pseudo-loan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pseudo-loan) would be an appropriate umbrella term for all above-mentioned instances. There is another rather rare term, [allogenism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/allogenism), which essentially describes the same phenomenon. However, I am not certain as to whether these two are accepted as linguistic terms, or rather just convenient designations.

Answer (score 4):

In German, there is the term [*Pseudoentlehnung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoentlehnung) or *Scheinentlehnung* for such kind of words, abstracting from the alledged original language. I think, you can use this term untranslated in a scholarly publication, I am not aware of an English translation of it.

Comment: Yes I came across that term on Wikipedia but I am not sure if it'd be proper for describing similar words in other languages. There really doesn't seem to a catch all English term in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I've *occasionally* seen this term, **pseudo-loans**, for instance in Louviot, Élise, and Catherine Delesse. 2017. Studies in language variation and change 2: Shifts and turns in the history of English:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Also called false loans, pseudo-borrowings and pseudo-formations

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! This post would benefit from adding further details. Being a one-line post, it may attract downvotes and criticism. Please [edit] it to add further relevant information — preferably with references to credible sources.